# How to develop Custom Adapter in Sightly

Tags: aem, sightly

I was going through sightly blog with practical. I have simple Use class as below :

```
public class SightlyDemo2 extends WCMUse {
    private String fullName;

    @Override
    public void activate() {

        fullName = get("firstName", String.class) + " " + get("lastName", String.class);
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

I am calling it successfully via below code in my .html file:

```
<div data-sly-use.aemComponent="${'org.practice.sightly.SightlyDemo2' @ firstName= 'AEM', lastName = 'CQ5'}">
    ${aemComponent.fullName}
</div>
```

It works fine, But when i try to create adapter class, It stop render the fullName. Below is the adapter code.

```
@Component(metatype = true, immediate = true)
@Service
public class SightlyDemo2Adapter implements AdapterFactory {
    @Property(name = "adapters")
    protected static final String[] ADAPTER_CLASSES = {SightlyDemo2.class.getName()};
    @Property(name = "adaptables")
    protected static final String[] ADAPTABLE_CLASSES = {Resource.class.getName()};
    @Override
    public <AdapterType> AdapterType getAdapter(Object adaptable, Class<AdapterType> type) {
        if (adaptable instanceof Resource) {
            SightlyDemo2 comp = new SightlyDemo2();
            return (AdapterType) comp;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to use the custom adapter like :

```
 SightlyDemo2 obj = resource.adaptTo(SightlyDemo2.class);
```

Any Idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an adapter to create a a class that extends WCMUse from an adapter, it wont work straightforward. When you use in Sightly a class that extends WCMUse, Sightly does not only instantiate it, but also calls the init() and activate() methods, which you cannot do in the AdapterFactory, since you don't have access to the scriptBindings from the resource.

If you need to use the SightlyDemo2 class from both sightly and and adaptTo(), I recommend you to drop the WCMUse. You could either retrieve any property you need from the resource and inject them into your pojo from the AdapterFactory, or even better, create a [Sling Model](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html) for it.